# manual array creation in R

Tags: r

I would like to know what is the most direct way to get a 2d array of point coordinates in the plan where :

- 2 point are at (0,1) and (0,-1)
- 200 points lie on the [-1,1] segment on x

I am going through functions but I feel like some R-fu would be it easily

Edit:

for info, I ended up doing that, but there has to be a better way...

```
x <- function(){
    z <- list()
    for (i in (0 : 200)){
        z[i] <- i/100 - 1
    }
    z[201] <- 0
    z[202] <- 0
    z
}

y <- function(){
    z <- list()
    for (i in (0 : 200)){
        z[i] <- 0 * (i/100 - 1) # 0 is to 'tilt' the segment
    }
    z[201] <- -1
    z[202] <- 1
    z
}

dgk <- data.frame(x = as.numeric(x()),
                  y = as.numeric(y()))
```

Comment: If it starts at (0,1) and goes to (0,-1), how can it include (-1,1)?

Comment: why do you want to order them ?

Comment: @nicolas?  What?  You really need to add a little more explanation about what you want.

Comment: @alexwhan, I don't think the points start and end at (0,1) and (0,-1) respectively. They're just 2 points.

Comment: @Dason where do you see a 'start' and an 'end' ? I am talking about a set of points. a set is not caracterized by a specific enumeration.

Comment: for-loops are very inefficient mechanisms to create sequences in R. Use `seq(-1, 1, len=200)`. Furthermore, indexing in R is 1 based and that 0 index will not create a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dgk <- data.frame(x = c(seq(-.99, 1, .01), 0, 0), y = c(rep(0, 200), -1, 1))
```

This matches your desired output.  It seems you just need to get familiar with `seq` and `rep`.

Edit: However this is probably closer to what you actually want

```
x <- c(seq(-1, 1, length.out = 200), 0, 0)
y <- c(rep(0, 200), -1, 1)
dgk <- data.frame(x, y)
```

I broke it up into several steps to more easily illustrate what is going on.

Comment: It does match his output, but his output doesn't match his requirements! If, as you say, you want -1 to 1 on x, you'll need to combine the two answers (since @Dason is giving you a `data.frame`)

Comment: @alexwhan - good point I guess.  I was basing the results mainly off their desired output since they didn't do a good job with the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking for, but how about:

```
ptcoords = cbind(x=c(0,0,runif(200,-1,1)), y=c(-1,1,rep(0,200)))
plot(ptcoords)
```

?

You can also incrementally cover -1 to 1 with seq(-1,1,length=200) instead of using runif().

Comment: interesting. this looks more idiomatic than what I did